# What is wrong in C# AngleSharp parse stream?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, anglesharp

Problem is that instead of the required number of headings, only a part is written to the document. Console output is OK.

here code:

```
using AngleSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace AngleSharp

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("ok start");
             Mainpar();
             Console.ReadKey();
        }
    static async Task Mainpar()
    {
        // Setup the configuration to support document loading
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        // Load the names of all The Big Bang Theory episodes from Wikipedia
        var address = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Big_Bang_Theory_episodes";
        // Asynchronously get the document in a new context using the configuration
        var document = await BrowsingContext.New(config).OpenAsync(address);
        // This CSS selector gets the desired content
        var cellSelector = "tr.vevent td:nth-child(3)";
        // Perform the query to get all cells with the content
        var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
        // We are only interested in the text - select it with LINQ
        var titles = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent).ToArray();

        var allnum = titles.Count();

        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\bd.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i <= allnum; i++)
        {
          sw.WriteLine(titles[i] + i);
          Console.WriteLine(titles[i] + i);
        }      
      }
   }
}
```

No idea what the problem is.A different number of headings are written to the file, and the latter is not completely.Maybe the thread is blocked or the program simply closes.. I do not understand how it depends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be closing the stream properly. What is probably happening is that the stream is being forcibly closed when your program closes without flushing to the file. Try wrapping in a using statement instead:

```
    using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\bd.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= allnum; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(titles[i] + i);
            Console.WriteLine(titles[i] + i);
        }
    }
```

The `using` statement makes sure that the stream is closed properly and flushed to the disk when you are finished using it.

Also, because you are not using `await` in your `MainPar` method, nor are you calling it using `await` in your main method, there isn't a good reason to mark it `async`. It should just be `static void`. Just adding the `async` keyword to the method doesn't help unless you call it asynchronously. If you wanted `MainPar` to really be async, you can use the [`StreamWriter.WriteLineAsync(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137902(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
    using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\bd.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= allnum; i++)
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(titles[i] + i);
            Console.WriteLine(titles[i] + i);
        }
    }
```

Which you can then call in your Main method like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok start");
            await Mainpar();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
```